# (document).ready functions have visible delay on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, load, document-ready

I have an element that has a class added to it on page load, via jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  $('.service_info_container').addClass('hide');

});
```

The class applies `display: none;` to the element, the issue I'm facing is that on page load, for a split second you see the element and then it disappears as the class is added it to, but I can't figure out why there is this delay. I have made sure my jQuery library and JS file are added before my stylesheets in the header, but it makes no difference. The staging site this occurs on has no form of script defers or similar optimizations.

It's my understanding that using `jQuery(document).ready` should fire right away once the script is loading in the DOM, or am I wrong and it needs to wait for other things like all images being loaded first? I acknowledge there are other approaches I could take but I really want to know why this one presents this issue. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready` fires after the **whole** DOM is loaded, not just the executing script.

Comment: Would using jQuery(window).load make more sense for my situation?

Comment: Once the entire `document` is loaded, the `document.ready` handler fires. It does not wait for external resources like images.

Comment: I would use the `<element class='service_info_container hide'>` approach.

Comment: Why not hide the element with CSS.

Comment: it's more about getting to the bottom of why there is a delay on this staging site and not others I have in very similar situations. The hiding the element aspect doesnt matter compared to the why is my JS being delayed.

Comment: Maybe you have a more complicated structure and longer loading times before the DOM is ready?

Comment: I absolutely hate to do this but because of time constraints I'm just going to add a page loader animation to hide the issue and come back to it later on, I don't think it's because the site is complex because the issue even happens on the extremely minimal framework I made that it's built on.

Comment: Far too many unknowns. Do some profiling in browser dev tools and online tools